# Calculate closest distance from a certain point to other many points

Tags: c#, random, distance, points, closest

I have a certain point such as `fixedPoint = (142, 12)`. And I want to create n (x, y) points randomly. Then I want to calculate closest distance from `fixedPoint` to other `(x,y)` point in C#.

Is there a tutorial that explains how to get this done? Or any sample code?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Did you even started an algorithm for that ?

Comment: Pretty sure your problem is more with the maths than with the code, in this case this is better suited for `maths.stackexchange`, however for calculating distance between two points pythagoras should be enough, here is a post: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/367503/127609

Comment: If it's the math: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Two_dimensions

Comment: Depends on the time you have and the amount of points you need to check. If you're working on a game, you'll probably need some space partitioning to limit the amount of distance checks you have to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just looping through the points and using the Pythagorean theorem to find distance, and keeping track of the best match.

Basically (pseudocode - it's been awhile since I've worked in C#):

```
struct Point
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
};



var fixed = new Point(142,42);

const int numberOfPoints = 20; // arbitrary number

List<Point> points = new List<Point>(numberOfPoints);

var random = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; ++i)
{
    int x = random.Next(-200,200);
    int y = random.Next(-200,200);
    points.Add(new Point(x,y));
}

Point closestPoint = null;
float closestDistanceSquared = float.Max;
/// find closest point to fixed
foreach(var point in points)
{
    var distanceSquared = Math.Pow(point.x - fixed.x,2) + Math.Pow(point.y - fixed.y,2);

    if (distanceSquared < closestDistanceSquared)
    {
        closestDistanceSquared = distanceSquared;
        closestPoint = point;
    }
}

/// closestPoint is now a reference to the closest to fixedPoint
/// distance between the two is Math.Sqrt(distanceSquared)
```

I use the squared distance rather than taking the square root within the loop since it's slightly more efficient, and sufficient for distance comparisons.

It's worth noting that you could do this while generating the points rather than having a separate loop.

Comment: @fdas You could add a variable `public int distanceToFixed` to keep track of distance for every points if you want more than remembering the closest one.

Comment: @ArthurRey true, but the advisability of that depends on whether the distance is fixed, or really applicable to Point rather than a polygon or other higher-order type. (If it makes semantic sense in the context of the needs of the application.)